# JScript runtime error: $.datepicker is null or not an object in _JqueryGlobalSettings

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am converting my mvc4 application to mobile friendly one.  When navigating to a certain page I am getting the $.datepicker is null or not an object error in _JqueryGlobalSettings.mobile.cshtml. In the desktop version I am not getting this error.  Pls Help.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
        changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
        showStatus: true,
        showWeeks: true,
        highlightWeek: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showAnim: "scale",
        showOptions: {
            origin: ["top", "left"]
                      }

    });
```

My _layout.mobile.cshtml is as follows

```
<head>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Mobile/Site.Mobile.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/custom-theme/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Icons/icons.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this  jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js